# GMAIL sent folder not accessible using IMAP

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch Gmail sent items using Imap but it gives me error saying "Notice: Unknown: [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: Sent (Failure) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0"

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Sent';
$username = 'anrc.wipro@gmail.com';
$password = '****************';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Answer (score 16):

I believe the 'Sent' folder is actually `[Gmail]/Sent Mail`

Comment: Beware that the folder names can be localized too.

Comment: THANKS i am able to access now using [Gmail]/Sent Mail ,can i  get list of folders in gmail account

Comment: Use XLIST to get folder names and their purpose (sent email, junk...): http://www.limilabs.com/blog/localized-gmail-imap-folders