# IMAP & PHP - Fetching all emails from sent and inbox folders

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap

I am trying to fetch any emails received and sent, and write it to the mySQL database using PHP.

The hostname I am using is:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
```

Which is referencing just the inbox, and successfully grabs just emails received.

To grab emails sent, I am trying to use this hostname:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail';
```

By replacing "INBOX" with "[Gmail]/All Mail", no emails (not even sent) and being returned.

How do I grab all emails sent and received?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is your problem related to MySQL itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to do this in two calls, inbox and sent items.  According to this post: [GMAIL sent folder not accessible using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007375/gmail-sent-folder-not-accessible-using-imap?rq=1), the sent items folder is called `[gmail]/sent mail`

Answer (score 7):

## You can use This code

```
$host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$mail_con = imap_open($host, $login, $password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($mail_con, $host, '*');
```

You can get array like this

```
Array(
    [0] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX
    [1] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}Personal
    [2] => {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}Servers
    [3] => {imap.ipage.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Sent Items
    [4] => {imap.ipage.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Drafts
)
```

remove above code and Use any array in imap_open like this

```
 $host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX.Sent';
 $mail_con = imap_open($host, $login, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what would have been the answer for this questions `9 years` ago but, the time I am posting it `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail` should be used instead and It worked for me. Here's the code sample for reference

```
    $mailBox = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail";
    $mailID = "fakeMail@test.com";
    $password = "Keep_me_secret_"; //use apps password here

    $imap = imap_open($msgBox, $mailID, $password);
    $count = imap_num_msg($imap);
    
    echo $count; //Total Number of Mails
```

[Apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

Actually this is very simple to fetch mails from all these folders, what you have to do is just make an folder extension like .Sent, .Drafts etc..

Example:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Sent'; //For Sent Items<br>
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Drafts';//For draft<br>
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Trash';//For trash<br>
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Junk';//For junk<br>
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.yourfolder';//For the folders u created
```