# How can i visualize as output a previously sent email?

Tags: php

I created a php code which makes possible the output visualization of all the recieved unreaded mails

```
  // server IMAP per la connessione
  $server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';

  // account Gmail
  $login = 'miaemail@gmail.com';

  // password per l'accesso a Gmail
  $password = 'miapassword';

  // connessione IMAP ad un account Gmail
  $connessione = imap_open($server, $login, $password);

  // numero di email ricevute
  $conteggio = imap_num_msg($connessione);

  // informazioni di tutte l'email ricevute
  $messaggi = imap_fetch_overview($connessione, "1:$conteggio");

  $k=1;
  // visualizza sono l'email non visualizzate
  for($i = 0; $i < $conteggio; $i++) {    
      $intestazioni = imap_headerinfo($connessione, $k);

     if($intestazioni->Unseen == 'U') {      
        echo "<p>Oggetto: ".$messaggi[$i]->subject."<br />";
        echo "Data: ".$messaggi[$i]->date."<br />";
        echo "Inviato da: ".$messaggi[$i]->from."</p>";
        echo $body = imap_fetchbody($connessione, $k, '1');        
     }

     $k++;
  }
```

I can’t find any imap function that allows me to query the email I sent.

Comment: Where does the code you have shown have _anything_ to do with videos? Super-massively unclear what you are even trying to ask here.

Comment: I hope i made it clearer

Comment: You need to specify which folder you actually want to read from then, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500077/imap-php-fetching-all-emails-from-sent-and-inbox-folders